# Start custom instrumentation from the app

Tags: android, android-testing

I am trying to start instrumentation test in my app with custom runner. All test and runner are situated inside my app for start moment.
I have added instrumentation name inside manifest manually:

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="MyCustomRunner"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:targetPackage="ru.busylee.runtestinapp">
</instrumentation>
```

Here is my custom runner. All the customization is addition logging on start create and etc:

```
public class MyCustomRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

  private static final String TAG = "MyCustomRunner";

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart()");
  }

  @Override
  public void finish(int resultCode, Bundle results) {
    super.finish(resultCode, results);
    Log.d(TAG, "finish()");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onException(Object obj, Throwable e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onException()");
    return super.onException(obj, e);
  }
}
```

Here is example how I am trying to start instrumentation:

```
if (!startInstrumentation(new ComponentName(this, MyCustomRunner.class), null, arguments)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "startInstrumentation failure");
            }
```

It works. I am able to run tests all in path, because I do not pass extra parameters using Bundle. But it does not use my custom runner, instead it uses `AndroidJUnitRunner` or stuff like that, because I do not see any log I added in my custom class. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Shouldn't the <instrumentation> tag refer to an Instrumentation class instead of a runner?

Comment: Yep, you right! But AndroidJUnitRunner is descendant of Instrumentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html)